# Which function crops images in wordpress?

Tags: php, images

I want to modify wordpress's core files to get a desired result for cropping and saving uploaded images. However, i can't find the function that handles the uploaded images and crops, renames and saves them.

I thought this function may have something to do with thumbnails :`wp_generate_attachment_metadata`

Can anyone help me which file and function does this?
Thank you

Comment: I would note the function that does this will be very expensive to run, you'll want to use add_image_size if you need to size images for your theme, and you'll want to do any cropping calls on the admin side, never on the frontend, else you could get pages that take minutes to load in the worst scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image goes through multiple processes for the thumbnail to be generated. Take a look into the `WP_Image_Editor` class in the `wp-includes/class-wp-image-editor.php`.

This class handles cropping, resizing, etc.

There is a public function inside this class, named `crop()`. This might be what you are after. However, the actual resizing is handled by the function `multi_resize()`, which generates thumbnails for each uploaded image.

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like it's [wp_crop_image](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_crop_image/) & [wp_ajax_crop_image](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_ajax_crop_image/)

Comment: Thank you. do there functions do the thumbnail generation? or they do the manual crop in the admin-side image edit page? i want the 1st one.

Comment: I've noticed that `image_downsize` does the thumbnail generation. @TomJNowell no, i wanted to modify wordpress's core to have completely custom thumbnail name, and directory structure.

Comment: Ah, you'd want to filter it, modifying core code directly is a terrible thing to do that opens up all sorts of difficult problems, such as them all being overwritten when you update